# Writing Matrix-Matrix products as sums

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, outer-product

$X = USV^\top = \sum_{i=1}^{rank(X)}s_{ii}u_i(v_i)^\top$

I'm trying to wrap my head around this reformulation.

$SV^\top$ does, of course, simply scale the rows of $V^\top$.

So if we write $X=AB^\top$, why can we write it as a sum $\sum_i a_i (b_i)^\top$ ?

Assuming $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, I know we can write $Ac = \sum_{i=1}^n c_ia_i$ and $c^\top A=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i ((A^\top)_i)^\top$, but these don't seem to be helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e_i$ is the $i$th column of an identity matrix, then $Ae_i$ the $i$th column of a matrix $A$. You can write $S$ as
$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^r s_ie_ie_i^T,
$$
where $e_ie_i^T$ is a matrix full of zeros expect the position of $s_i$ in $S$. Substitute it to get
$$
USV^T=U\left(\sum_{i=1}^r s_ie_ie_i^T\right)V^T=
\sum_{i=1}^r s_i (Ue_i)(e_i^TV^T)=
\sum_{i=1}^r s_i (Ue_i)(Ve_i)^T=
\sum_{i=1}^r s_i u_iv_i^T.
$$

Comment: So for $X=AB^\top$, we have $s_i = 1$ and $X=\sum_i a_i (b_i)^\top$. Thanks a lot. I'm always surprised how very simple things look in hindsight. (Unfortunately, only ever in hindsight.)

Comment: @User1291 Yes. Note that $I=\sum_ie_ie_i^T$. So $X=AB^T=AIB^T=A(\sum_ie_ie_i^T)B^T=\sum_i a_ib_i^T$ by the same "trick".